# calculating the difference of date from report and date from server

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I would like to calculate the difference between 2 dates from a report generated in our system.
The date is stored in the system as sdCreateDate, but I can't seem to use 
`SELECT DateDiff(d,'sdCreateDate','GetDate()')` to get the difference displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DateDiff(d, sdCreateDate, GetDate())
```

The error was with your parameters.  You can't put single quotes on `sdCreateDate` and `getdate()`.  Instead of string literals, you need to have the field name and the function call.

[DATEDIFF() MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)